# Is it possible to connect a P2P IP Camera to a mobile router wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, wifi-configuration, ip-camera

I have purchased a [Megapixel Wireless P2P IP Camera](http://www.dx.com/p/ipcc-b12n-w-waterproof-720p-p2p-h-264-onvif-wireless-ip-camera-w-email-alert-motion-detection-385594#.Veq8kPntmko) and I'm having trouble configuring it. It seems when I read the manuals that I need to make a wired connection with a RJ45 network cable to my router in order to make the IP camera visible in my wireless home network.

My problem is that **I do not have** a wireless router to which I can connect the IP Camera to with a RJ45 cable.

I have a [mobile router Huawei E5776s-32](http://www.starhub.com/content/dam/business/support/Internet/userguides/PDF/e5776-quick-start-guide.pdf) in my possession, which does not have a socket place for RJ45 cable. I cannot use a [basic router (e.g. zyxel)](http://www.zyxel.com/fi/fi/products_services/nbg6616.shtml?t=p) because my household does not have the required wiring so a mobile router is my only option at the moment.

I have two questions regarding this matter:

> 1. Is it possible to connect the P2P IP Camera to the Huawei mobile router wirelessly without a RJ45 network cable in order to make the
>      camera visible in my home network?
> 2. If I get a basic wireless router (with RJ45 sockets) that allows me to connect devices into it with a RJ45 cable, then is it possible to
>      use the wireless router as a bridge between the IP Camera and the
>      mobile wireless router?

I would prefer of course the option 1.

Thank you for any help! Please let me know if you need clarifications or more details

P.S. if this is the wrong stack.exchange site to ask this I can remove my question. If this is the case, what would be the correct stack.exchange site?

Comment: "because my household does not have the required wiring" - how are you getting your internet connection?

Comment: By a mobile internet connection.

Comment: What I meant above is that my household does not have the required wiring to connect router to internet via RJ45 cable. This is why I must use a mobile router, which includes a sim-card.